# Nilpotent Matrix is Similar to a block diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

Prove that any nilpotent matrix is similar to a block diagonal matrix whose blocks are matrices with 1's along the first super diagonal and 0's elsewhere.

I'm not sure where to start exactly. Any guidance would be helpful!

Comment: I am assuming over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Can you use Jordan canonical form?  Combine with the fact that the eigenvalues of a nilpotent matrix are all $0$.

Comment: Do you know about quotient spaces?

Comment: I think this is sometimes a stepping-stone to the full Jordan canonical form theorem. It doesn't matter what the base field is. You can build up a basis of the vector space with the required properties. Take $x\not=0$; there is some minimal $k$ such that $N^k x=0$. It's easy to prove that $\{x,Nx,N^2x, \dots,N^{k-1}x\}$ is LI, and action of $N$ on these is "right". Now take $x_2$ outside the span of these and repeat.

Comment: Check Daniel's answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809473/generalization-of-the-jordan-form-for-infinite-matrices/918339#918339

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on Wikipedia articles ["Nilpotent matrix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix) and ["Jordan normal form."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)

Every square matrix *A* over an algebraically-closed field has a Jordan canonical form *J*, which has zeros everywhere except *A*'s eigenvalues as diagonal entries and possibly ones on the super diagonal. *A* is similar to *J* because there exists an invertible matrix *P* such that *A* = *P J P* ⁻¹.  Because zero is the only eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix, *J* has the form you want.